# Scalar QED photon vacuum polarization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, self-energy

Consider a calculation of photon vacuum polarization in scalar QED. The 1PI diagram which people calculate is this one,

[image]

But in scalar QED the seagull vertex is also possible

[image]

Then why not include a diagram like this one,

[image]

Which would then make the propagator sum to go something like this,

[image]

and so on.

Now my question is am I correct to add such a diagram? If not why? Also if indeed such terms are added in a full calculation please refer to articles which take these contributions into account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a completely valid diagram, but it's higher order in perturbation theory. The 3-point vertex comes with a factor of $e$, and the 4-point vertex comes with a factor of $e^2$, so your diagram is order $e^4$, which is higher than the order $e^2$ contributions calculated in standard textbooks. Note that for the purposes of computing corrections to the propagator in this theory, "order $e^2$" is synonymous with "one loop", and "order $e^4$" is synonymous with "two loop".

Two loop corrections can be found in various papers. For example, [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0550321302002602) claims to calculate two-loop corrections in scalar QED using dimensional regularization.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that the seagull diagram contributes, and there's even an important contribution at the same order as the first diagram you drew:

[image]

You can find an explicit evaluation of that diagram in dim reg in Srednicki's book, in Section 65.